# Mocking a method that takes a delegate in RhinoMocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I have the following classes:

```
public class HelperClass  
{  
    HandleFunction<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
         // Custom logic here

         func.Invoke();

         // Custom logic here  
}

// The class i want to test  
public class MainClass
{
    public readonly HelperClass _helper;

    // Ctor
    MainClass(HelperClass helper)
    {
          _helper = helper;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
         // Use the handle method
         _helper.HandleFunction(() =>
        {
             // Foo logic here:
             Action1();
             Action2(); //etc..
        }
    }
}
```

I want to test `MainClass` only.  I a using RhinoMocks to mock `HelperClass` in my tests.
The problem is, while I am not interested in testing the `HandleFunction()` method I am interested in checking `Action1`, `Action2` and other actions that were sent to `HandleFunction()` when called..
How can I mock the `HandleFunction()` method and while avoiding it's inner logic, invoke the code that was sent to it as a parameter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because your unit under test most probably requires the delegate to be called before proceeding, you need to call it from the mock. There is still a difference between calling the real implementation of the helper class and the mock implementation. The mock does not include this "custom logic". (If you need that, don't mock it!)

```
IHelperClass helperMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IHelperClass>();
helperMock
  .Stub(x => x.HandleFunction<int>())
  .WhenCalled(call => 
  { 
    var handler = (Func<int>)call.Argument[0];
    handler.Invoke();
  });

// create unit under test, inject mock

unitUnderTest.Foo();
```

Comment: Another way to do this would be for the `Func<>` to be a first-class member (property) of the class you're testing.  Your class just calls `_helper.HandleFunction(myFunc);`; you provide a default implementation of myFunc in the class, but replace it for your unit test.

Comment: `Argument[0]` should be `Arguments[0]`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Stefan's answer I'd like to show quite another way to define stub which invokes passed argument:

```
handler
    .Stub(h => h.HandleFunction(Arg<Func<int>>.Is.Anything))
    .Do((Action<Func<int>>)(func => func()));
```

Please read more about `Do()` handler [here](http://ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+The+Do%28%29+Handler.ashx) and [here](http://ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+The+Do%28%29+Handler.ashx?Discuss=1).

Comment: Thanks!
However this specific example won't work. The delegate expected in the DO function is obligated to return the same type as the stubbed function (in this example it's int)

Comment: Have you tried it? In your example `HanldeFunction()` returns nothing :). I assume, it returns `void`. If the actual signature of `HanldeFunction()` differs from my assumption, just pass the another appropriate lambda to the `Do()` handler.